# Sort list according given text of months

Tags: python

How to sort the given list `l` according to months `['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar']` and `['L', 'K']`:

```
l = ['Jan_K', 'Mar_K', 'Feb_L']
```

The expected result should be:

```
result = ['Feb_L', 'Jan_K', 'Mar_K']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your try is a list comprehension which actually does nothing else than creating a new list.

If you want to sort a list, you gave to use [`.sort()`](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting#Sorting_Basics).

If you want to sort a list in a particular way, you have to use `.sort()` with the [`key`](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting#Key_Functions) argument.

So, if you want the first months to come first in the list, start by creating a list containing the order of these months:

```
months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]
```

Then, you can use `key` and a lambda function like this:

```
l.sort(key=lambda x: months.index(x.split('_')[0]))
```

For example, `x.split('_')[0]` gives `"Jan"` when `x` is `"Jan_opi"`, and `months.index("Jan")` is `0` so the element will come first.

---

According to your edit, if you want to sort the list based on two criterias, you just have to make the lambda function return a tuple (the sorting function compares the first value returned of two elements, and if it is the same then the second one).

```
letters = ['L','K']
final_result = sorted(l, key=lambda x: (letters.index(x.split('_')[1]), months.index(x.split('_')[0])))
```

Comment: @thito How could not it be in the list? It is the first value in the `months` list as you can see.

Comment: This is the better way forward, as you tool yourself for using a key with any arbitrary list. For completeness, note that you can use the same key arg with `sorted` for `sorted(l,key=lambda x: months.index(x.split('_')[0]))`.

Comment: @Delgan, Shawn Mehan Again I want to sort the result according to `['kio','xdf']`. Can you help me getting `final_result`?

Comment: @thito You can not use two keys argument, but you can rearrange the lambda function I set so it suits your need. If I understood correctly, you want the elements to be sort according to `['kio','xdf']`, and if the value is the same, then sort according to the month? Then, you lambda function could return a tuple of 2 values. The sort function compares the first value and put the lowest to the head's list. If the value are the same, the sort function check the second one. So, it gives: `lambda x: (x.split('_')[1], months.index(x.split('_')[0]))`

Comment: But if you just want a different sorting only based on `['kio','xdf']` without considering month, you might use `final_result = sorted(l, key=lambda x: x.split('_')[1])`.

Comment: @Delgan yes, but your sorted ['kio','xdf'] according to the ascii character, i want to sort it according to the elements as given in the list. How to do it?

Comment: @Delgan Anyway for my real problem, please show me sorting by two cases as you did before.

Comment: @thito Ok, I see. You can use the same way I did for the months using `.index()`, but this time with the others values. Like `suffixes = ['kio','xdf']`, and `final_result = sorted(l, key=lambda x: (suffixes.index(x.split('_')[1]), months.index(x.split('_')[0])))`.

Comment: @Delgan Thanks it solved my problem. BTW why the last argument should be closed by ()?

Comment: @thito The lambda function have to return an explicit tuple, like `lambda x: (x[0], x[1])`. If you do not add parenthesis, this will probably raises an error because there will be a confilct with the sorting comma: `sorted(l, key=lambda x:x[0], x[1])`, Python does not know that the lambda function returns two values, so `x[1]` will be considered as an argument to the `sorted` function.