# Python: Sorting month names from a glob

Tags: python

I'm working on a script to generate a readme file for a repository of release notes based off of the repo's filenames.

This is the repo's file structure

```
/2017
/2017/README.md
/2017/January
/2017/January/README.md
/2017/January/version#.md
```

What we've had for the repo README in the past is a TOC with all the various versions listed out under their respective year and month.

```
## [2017](/2017/README.md)
### [January](/2017/January/README.md)
- [version#](/2017/January/version#.md)
```

This is a pain to manually update, so I turned to python. This is the script I have so far:

```
import pathlib, os, glob, fnmatch, re, datetime
from pathlib import Path

with open('README.md', 'w') as output:
            sorter = glob.glob('**/*.md')
            for filename in sorter:
                if fnmatch.fnmatch(filename, '20??/README.md'):
                    file = re.search(r'\d+', filename)
                    output.write('\n## ' + '[' + file.group(0) + '](' + str(filename)+ ')\n')
                if fnmatch.fnmatch(filename, '20??/*/README.md'):
                    file = re.search(r'\w[a-z]+', filename)
                    output.write('\n### ' + '[' + str(file.group(0)) + '](' + str(filename)+ ')\n')
                if fnmatch.fnmatch(filename, '20??/*/v*.md'):
                    file = re.search(r'v\d+', filename)
                    output.write('- ' + '[' + str(file.group(0)) + '](' + str(filename)+ ')\n')
```

This is currently producing the README as desired, but because I'm using a glob, the output is unordered. Is there an easy way to sort by month names, or should I start looking at parsing the glob into a structure that handles ordering better?

Update:
I'd disagree that this is *exactly* the same as [Sort list according given text of months](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33767899/sort-list-according-given-text-of-months) due to the depths of the filenames (eg, 2017/january vs 2016/january), but it's a better answer than I was finding searching on my own, so I'll take it. I'm thinking I'll split the data up a little more and then use the sort on key method.

Comment: what's your input & expected output?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33767899/sort-list-according-given-text-of-months

Comment: Use `sorted` with an appropiate key.

Comment: With respect to what's "exact" enough to be amenable to close-as-duplicate -- we encourage folks to edit questions to remove incidental complexity and focus on the meat of the problem (to make questions and their answers useful and applicable to as many people as possible), so if something has incidental complexity unrelated to the core of the question and its solutions, that doesn't generally argue against being flagged as duplicate.